# Laravel5: Access public variable in another class

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I have a middleware file called `LanguageMiddleware.php`:

```
...
class LanguageMiddleware {

    //ISO language codes:
    public $languages = ['en','es','fr','de','pt','pl','zh','ja'];
    ...
```

`LanguageMiddleware.php` is in `laravelProj/app/Http/Middleware/`

Here's my problem: I have a blade template file called `master.blade.php` where I'm attempting to output a list of languages

```
@foreach (App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware\languages as $lang)
    <a class=\"setLang\" href=\"lang/en\">{{ Locale::getDisplayLanguage($lang, $lang) }}</a><br>
@endforeach
```

I need to access the `$languages` variable in `LanguageMiddleware.php`

`master.blade.php` is in `laravelProj/resources/views/layouts/`

How to access variables in another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple php stuff. Set the attribute as `static` and access it with `::`.

```
class LanguageMiddleware {
    public static $languages = ['en','es','fr','de','pt','pl','zh','ja'];
}

@foreach (App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::$languages as $lang)
    ...
@endforeach
```

You should not have that in a middleware though. You'd better add a configuration (i.e in */config/app.php*) with that array, and access it with `Config::get`.

Comment: Seconded: if languages need to be accessed outside of the middleware, then move them out of the middleware to somewhere that is accessible by both.

Comment: I know it might seem simple, but I am only finding this stuff out and am trying to do it the right way. Thank you for your tip about Config::get... That is certainly what I should be doing!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have a class with a function that can be access outside of its scope. I normally do something like this one here:

In app directory you can create a new directory (e.g libs),

put `LanguageMiddleware.php` in there,

```
class LanguageMiddleware{
 static function languages($lang){
   //Do your languages code here
}
}
```

In `app/start/global.php` add a`pp_path().'/libs'` to you  `addDirectories`,
Then in `composer.json` add `"app/libs"` to `autoLoad` array.

In your blade template you can do:

```
@foreach(LanguageMiddleware::languages($lang))
  <a class=\"setLang\" href=\"lang/en\">{{ Locale::getDisplayLanguage($lang, $lang) }}</a><br>
@endforeach
```

This way the class and its function is now available wherever you want to call it in your project.